# Issues with replacing Spree Commerce layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am currently starting to build a custom frontend for a Spree application and I was wondering how to go about it.
I have read the Spree Commerce Documentation and it sais there are two ways of customizing views.

- the Deface library
- replacing the views in the Rails folder

In the docs it is stated that

> Whenever you copy an entire view into your extension or application you are adding a significant maintenance overhead to your application when it comes to upgrading to newer versions of Spree. When upgrading between versions you need to compare each template that’s been replaced to ensure to replicate any changes from the newer Spree version in your locally copied version.
>
> To this end we strongly suggest you use Deface to achieve the desired customizations wherever possible.

I would have to replace all of the front-end views but I am afraid that this will prevent me or others to update to another version of Spree. Defacing seems a bit overly complicated in my case...

Can anyone tell me how big of a problem replacing the views will be in regard of the above stated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are around 48 views in the front end of Spree.  By replacing all of them in your own application, every tie you want to upgrade Spree, you will need to determine what has changed between your views, and Spree's views between the two Spree versions, check if any templates have been added or removed, and then figure out how to modify your views to conform to the expectations of a new version of spree.  This will be a lot of work.

I'd recommend you re-evalute why you need to change all of Spree's views?  Take a look at the [spree_fancy](https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy) extension.  They are able to completely change the look & feel of Spree while only replacing a small subset of the views, and using Deface to add content and markup where needed.  An extensions like this would be much easier to port to future versions of Spree than if they had replaced all of the views.  We manage many Spree sites, and have several significantly customized front ends, and have not yet had to resort to techniques beyond Deface, and CSS changes.

If your front end is radically different, and using the existing Spree front end will be too cumbersome, you may want to consider building your front end using the Spree API.  The API is designed to have more stable inputs and output between versions, which will make upgrading Spree much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would it be possible that you sent me examples of strongly customized shops you have been working on? Just so I can get an idea of what is possible

Comment: The best place to start for a customized site would be https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy  as you have the source for that.  The most recent SpreeConf had a keynote by Andy Dunn talking about their most recent site https://www.ayr.com/ which is based on Spree.  You won't have the source for that, but it gives you a good idea of some of the things that are possible.

Comment: I did that and tried it out. Are you sure ayr.com is based on Spree Fancy? The thing is Bryan Quinn (CTO of Spree Commerce) said in a post in the Spree Google Group "Most larger Spree implementations generally override 70% to 80% of the front-end views, while smaller sites typically only do a few small tweaks (sometimes only using Deface)." (Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/B17492QdnGA)

Comment: I don't believe the Ayr site is based on spree_fancy.  It is likely a custom front end built on top of Spree.  I recommend Spree fancy because you have the source for it and can see how it does everything.  Overall, the decision on how to implement your site should depend on a number of factors, including your familiarity and comfort with Spree.  It wouldn't be the place that I'd recommend that you start, but if you need a highly specific front end, then writing your own or using the Spree API are going to be your best options.